# Java Update Jar command not working (using Runtime.getRuntime().exec())

Tags: java, command-line, jar, runtime

So I am making this builder that is supposed to simply make a config.java file, put the config info it. Compile it. then update an existing jar with it. I have everything working and I am getting no errors, however when I do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar uf "+out+" "+ cClass);` it seems to fail. I have tried getting the output of said command but it is showing nothing. I also tried to do this manually and it worked fine. So my question is, what is going wrong and how do I fix it?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac "+config);         
File cClass = new File (config.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() +"/configs.class");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar uf "+out+" "+ cClass);
```

Out is the Jar file to be updated, config is the config.java cClass is the config.class

Here is My entire UpdateJar class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class cmd extends Thread{
private File out;
private File config;
public cmd(File out, File config){
    this.out = out;
    this.config = config;
    this.start();
}
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar uvf "+out+" "+config.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+("/configs.class"));
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            System.out.println(stdInput.readLine());
            System.out.println(stdError.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

The output it returns is such:

```
2013-03-28 20:18:58.363 null
2013-03-28 20:18:58.363 [parsing started RegularFileObject[/Users/jorisbolsens/Desktop/configs.java]]
2013-03-28 20:19:04.364 adding: Users/jorisbolsens/Desktop/configs.class(in = 767) (out= 512)(deflated 33%)
2013-03-28 20:19:04.364 null
```

Out of curiosity I extracted all the files of my out.jar and found that the `configs.class` is in fact being put into the jar, it is simply being put into a folder. into `users.jorisbolsens.Desktop` to be specific.

Comment: What have you done by `I have tried getting the output of said command but it is showing nothing.`? Could you please show us the code?

Comment: I did `Process p = runtime stuff` then used in.readLine() to get whatever the runtime returned, but it returned nothing, just like it does when done manually.

Comment: Have you checked both `InputStream` and `ErrorStream`?

Comment: There are 3 things often differ in such scenarios: 1. new File(".").getAbsolutePath() 2. Environment Variables 3. User rights

Comment: @ericson yes errorstream also returns null

Comment: It's odd, the `jar` command would print out some error messages if there is any error. Could you provide the code for reading the output stream? You can use `jar uvf` instead of `jar uf` to get verbose output(the files being updated to the jar will be printed out in the stdout).

Comment: @ericson I have added the code, changed to `uvf` and added the output. While it seems to have updated correctly, the jar still contains the original `configs.class` file, the `configs.java` file was created and edited successfully

Comment: I think the `jar` part is working as expected. You might need check if you have the right class file before running `jar` command. Your code is running in a separate threads so it is possible to run out of order. You can print out the modification timestamp of the class file to verify.

Comment: @ericson, added output of both processes with timestamp as requested.
also, I am sure I have the correct class file as I have manually updated using an identical command and it worked fine. (also decompiled the resulting class file and it was correct)

Comment: I just noticed you missed the `Process.waitFor` method invocation after `javac` command. Try adding it?

Comment: @ericson Just realized that it adds my configs to another folder, check OP for info, also, thanks for the `Process.waitFor()` thing, that's really helpfull

Comment: Thanks ericson for the help, I fixed it by adding the -C option, will answer this to avoid confusion.

Comment: Nice. I should have reminded you to use `jar tf <foo.jar>|grep configs.class` to check if the class is in the right directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, It was so simple that I feel really stupid for not trying this at first. I changed the

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar uvf "+out+" "+config.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+("/configs.class"));
```

part to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar uvf "+out+" -C "+config.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+ " configs.class");
```

and everything works perfectly now. I would like to thank ericson for all his help.